# How to animate a view or button with fragment transition?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I created a ViewPager with 5 fragments. Each fragment has a button. I want to rotate that button with fragment transition. What happens that all the five buttons rotate when I start the activity, so I only see the rotation of the button of the first fragment. This is the code I used for each fragment:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.quote_1, container, false);

        quoteOneShareButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.q_one_share_btn);
        //code to rotate share btn with fragment transition:
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        rotateAnimation1.setDuration(1500);
        rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        quoteOneShareButton.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
        //end of rotation code
        return rootView;
    }
```

I want the animation of each button to start only when  I get to the fragment that contains it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because all 5 fragments get created almost the same time, so you shouldn't start the animation inside the `onCreateView` instead start it when the fragment is visible to the user.

You can achieve this by calling the `onResume` method inside each fragment, but you **must** call `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT` behavior in the constructor of the ViewPager adapter.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    // animtion code..
}
```